# Referencing Public Constants in Cell Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, cell, formula, constants

I would like to be able reference a public constant in a cell formula. I have found multiple references to **defining constants** *from* cell values, but not for using constants in formulas.

I would like to be able do something like this (I know that this is not the right syntax, but you get the idea...)

```
="Some formula text " & myPublicConstantName
```

Ideas?

Thank!

Comment: FWIW cell values cannot be *constant*. Curious what references you found suggesting a constant can be defined from a cell's value.

Answer (score 3):

Your public constant lives in a standard module, and probably looks something like this:

```
Public Const Foo As Long = 42
```

You can expose it through a UDF:

```
Public Function GetFoo() As Long
    GetFoo = Foo
End Function
```

And now you can have `="some formula text " & GetFoo()` in a worksheet cell.

Comment: Thanks, Matthieu. Since I have many constants I need to fetch in this way (all text), I'll try something like:


`    Public Function strGetConstant (strConstant as String) As String
        strGetConstant = strConstant
    End Function`


...and in the cell formula...


    ="Some prefix text " & strGetConstant(gcStrTheConstantINeed) & " some suffix text"

Will let you know how it goes...

Comment: Sorry "Mathieu" -- the approach a tried based on your suggestion (`="My Prefix " & strGetConstant(gcStrProcess) & " my suffix"` returns a #VALUE error. FYI, the constant in question is declared as `Public Const gcStrProcess As String = "Process"'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused what you mean by "I have found multiple references to defining constants from cell values." I think you're looking for a VBA solution (?), but just in case you're not, you can just define a name and you're good to go:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was an aside. I didn't know to what extent the answer involved VBA or an Excel formula or some combination of the two. I thinks Matthiew provided the answer -- but thanks!

Comment: @user11388509 feel free to mark Matthieu's answer as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left.

Comment: To clarify -- I need to populate a cell with a combination of static text concatenated with a string constant value. The aside was to say that I had found solutions to an issue other than the one I am having, and that they were not what I was looking for. I could not find answers that addressed my specific need.

Comment: It seems like you could use `Select Case` within a function similar to Matthieu's to return a constant depending on the input.