# Can I define a constant in VBA to be used in Excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, constants

Instead of using the same defined name in multiple workbooks, can I define a constant in my xlam file that can then be used in all my workbooks?

For example, in VBA:

```
Public Const nKilobyte = 1024
```

Then in a worksheet:

```
=A1 / nKilobyte
```

I tried this and I get a `#NAME?` error. Right now, it looks like a worksheet can refer to functions defined in VBA, but not constants. So as a workaround, I made up the following function:

```
Public Function vConstant(sName As String) As Variant
    Select Case sName
        Case "kb": vConstant = 1024
        Case "Mb": vConstant = 1024 ^ 2
      End Select
End Function
```

which I can then call in a worksheet as:

```
=A1 / vConstant("kb")
```

That works, but an actual constant would be better. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Similar/related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56465548/1188513

Answer (score 1):

> That works, but an actual constant would be better. Is there a way to do that?

Nope.

Excel and VBA are two separate things: they talk to each other using a predefined pipeline, and that interface says public procedures in standard modules are exposed as "macros", and public functions in standard modules are exposed as user-defined functions. In the other direction, VBA gets to talk to Excel through its object model.

The Excel calc engine knows nothing of the VBA runtime context that's holding the runtime values of your global variables and constants: that's purely on the VBA side of things. In fact, it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume a constant doesn't even exist in the compiled code - that's actually the case in C# code: the compiler "burns" the value of constants in-place, at the call sites. I wouldn't be surprised to crack open the compiled p-code and find that all constants are just inlined into their call sites... but that's all just speculation.

For whatever it's worth, that magic-string driven function isn't ideal; callers might end up scratching their heads wondering whether it wants "KB", "Kb", "kB" or "kb" (`Option Compare Binary` being the default string comparison mechanism in VBA, i.e. case-sensitive), or maybe it was "KiB"? Make sure the supported values are well-documented, and use `StrComp` with *text* rather than *binary* comparison to make the match case-insensitive.

Consider exposing a single function / UDF per constant. That'll eliminate the magic strings and enhance the UDF usability.

```
Public Function BytesInKB() As Long
    BytesInKB = CLng(1024)
End Function

Public Function BytesInMB() As Long
    BytesInMB = CLng(1024) ^ 2
End Function
```